# How to change background color depending on the day of the week using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I need to change the background color of the header box according to the day of the week. For example if the day is Monday or Wednesday the background of the header should be pink, otherwise it should be blue. I found something like this online but it doesn't work. Also I'm not sure where to put the if statement, in the head or the body part? I put this code in the head part and it didn't work.

```php
$t = date("l");
if ($t == 'Monday' || $t == 'Wednesday') {
    echo "<body style='background-color:pink'>";
} else {
    echo "<body style='background-color:blue'>";
}
```

Anything I found online was with javascript and I don't know js (I'm very new to coding) so I'm not sure If I should learn and use it or try something else.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: How exactly does it _not work_? Works fine over here ~ https://3v4l.org/nh3oU

Comment: You put this PHP code instead of your body tag.

Comment: @AnthonyBird how can you tell that? OP hasn't provided any such context and we have no idea what the actual problem is

Comment: @Phil He said he put the tag IN the head. It appears that he didn't realize it generated the body tag.

Comment: @AnthonyBird ah, good catch. OP should put this code immediately after `</head>`

Comment: but the thing is when i put it in the body tag, the background color of the whole page changes, but i need only the header part to change.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't know PHP, but if you're interested in trying JavaScript, which in this case has some advantages, you can do it like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function setBgColor() {
        const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        const today = new Date().getDay();
        let color;
        if (today == 1 || today == 3) { // Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, etc.
          color = "pink";
        } else {
          color = "blue";
        };
        body.setAttribute("style", "background-color: " + color + ";");
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="setBgColor()">
    <p>Hello, world!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is much better because it uses the client's local time to determine the day of the week

Answer (score 0):

Check and return the `color` value, then use it in the body.

```
<?php

$day = date("l");
$color = ($day == "Monday" || $day == "Wednesday") ? 'pink' : 'blue';

?>

<body style="background-color: <?= $color ?>;">

</body>
```

Comment: If OP's code _doesn't work_ then this won't either

Comment: Because what I think is the OP doesn't want to echo the whole body tag.

Comment: But your answer does exactly the same thing 

Comment: Is it? I thought it was different when echoing the body tag & just echoing the color in the body tag. The OP is not sure where to put the `if` statement, is it in the head or body. Then I think this would help.

Comment: Both OP's code and your code produce exactly the same result (except yours has `</body>`)

Comment: You is right, adding another `style="background-color:pink!important` would help too